# Congratulations Quantum Computing - You are now three years old!

Tags: discussion, community

Three. Three years old we are today.

---

And now we are two years old.

---

Today is an important event of this site. Some of us were reminded of it by a special badge that they earned for the first time on this site.

I am talking about the Yearling badge. This badge shows us that the site has been existing now for more than a year.

I want to say thanks to everyone for their commitment and support of the community. It doesn't matter whether you joined this site one year ago or just yesterday. Without all of us, the site would not be as it is today.

Everyone can be extremely proud of themselves and for this, I donate this cake to all of you:

[image: Cake]

<sup>The original uploader was Pill at German Wiktionary. CC BY-SA 3.0, http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/, via Wikimedia Commons</sup>

I also want to thank our moderators that kept the site clean and are all extremely professional:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I also want to thank everyone who is active on the site, especially all these people with more than 2000 reputation:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Oh and one more thing. I have a little question/task for you, too:

**What is your favorite event, post or anything else of this site?**

Comment: Woo! Thanks everyone for all their hard work in making this site a success. Here's to many years to come!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to everyone for your efforts so far! While the amount of time I can spend on here is sadly limited (I have a PhD to finish soon, so I don't have as much time as I'd like to answer questions), I've managed to come across some great posts, so I'll just share my absolute favourites here:

[Explicit Lieb-Robinson Velocity Bounds](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1620/23) - I'd never heard of velocity bounds before this, although it turns out they're (and the ideas they bring) are relevant for many things, such as simulating quantum computers on a classical computer.

[Quantum simulation of environment-assisted quantum walks in photosynthetic energy transfer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1854/23) - that environmental loss has the potential to *improve* the transport of a signal is amazing and something I'd really like to look into someday.

[Answer to Intuitive Proof: BQP ⊆ PP](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/5213/23) - Delving into the details of this answer really helped me understand how the different (quantum relevant) complexity classes work in comparison with classical complexity classes. Also helped me figure out just what's going on with the concepts behind how things like topological quantum computing came into being - although they're not mentioned in this answer, I was led there via DAGs and number of accepting paths.

Answer (score 4):

I am fond of many questions and answers on this site.

Some that come to mind include:

- [This one](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8729/why-is-the-probability-vector-of-a-uniformly-random-state-sum-i-alpha-ii-rang) about the probability of uniformly random states over different fields ($\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{R}$, etc.) along with the nice tie-in to the [Sphere and the Cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Sphere_and_Cylinder).
- [This one](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9264/is-quantum-teleportation-a-natural-phenomenon) inquiring about whether quantum teleportation would ever be considered a "natural" phenomenon.  I like it because it forces thinking about the bare minimum of what teleportation may require.
- [This one](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9891/can-we-combine-the-square-roots-inside-the-definition-of-the-fidelity) on simplification of fidelity calculations.